# Program Creating Random Folder Names in Local App Data

Tags: c#, wpf

I am making my first ever Desktop application using a Visual Studio WPF C# Project.  It is essentially a desktop version of our ourline portal and as such is heavily API dependent with all the data being requested from the API and then displayed on screen.

The creates a lag and therefore I want to cache the data (most of which does not change reguarly).  It makes sense that this should be stored in the Local User AppData folder as the data may be different for each logged on user.

Following how other programs store data I had intended to use a folder structure like (..\AppData\Local\MyCompany\MyAppName).  However Visual Studio seems to have created it's own folder to save the User Settings file.  This has a random name of MyApp.exe_Url_zxoieepjoj5f20tv5rvyiv330bs2l02k under the company name and also has subfolders I don't need based on the version number.

Therefore I have two questions:

1. How do I change the location the User Settings file is saved?  This is data I would want to persist between versions of the program and ideally would like in contained with the '..\AppData\Local\MyCompany\MyAppName' folder.
2. How should I save my cached data into the same folder?  At present I am getting the Local AppData location from 'Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)' then appending the Company Name and Program Name manually in the code to get a Directory Reference.  I was intending to use this reference to create and save files.

I'm sorry for the long question, but hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Please post the code you are using to save the data on your question, so we can try to help.

Comment: I'm not yet saving any data.  I was about to start working on that section of code, begining with creating the intermediate folders, when I found the 'random named' folder.  Not sure where it came from or how to rename it I was somewhat lost and came here for help!

Comment: And at what point is that folder created? Is there some piece of code that creates that folder when executed?

Comment: There are way too many unknowns for us to even guess what might be going on. You have to reduce your problem to a [Minimal Complete Verifiable example ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and post that to your question.

Comment: That looks like the appsettings file folder.

Comment: Nothing I have writen explicitally creates the folder.  However it is saving data from the Settings.settings file.  It appears to be created during the login process, which is when I get the API Key from the server and this is saved.  THe code for that is: 'Properties.Settings.Default.apiKey = login.result.apiKey;
                Properties.Settings.Default.Save();'

Comment: I have managed to solve the second part of my question.  The property I was looking for was  Application.LocalUserAppDataPath.  This gives my a 'clean' location to cache data. Unfortunately this still leaves the AppSettings folder in a separate directory.